# Python DB API list tables

Tags: python, database, python-db-api

How do I list a DB's tables with Python's DB API?

Failing that, is there another way to do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The DBAPI does not have a function for this so unfortunately you need to use SQL that is specific to the database engine (there is no standardized way to list tables).

- MySQL: [`SHOW TABLES`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/show-tables.html)
- PostgreSQL: [`SELECT tablename FROM pg_tables WHERE schemaname = 'public'`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/view-pg-tables.html)
- SQLite: [`SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type = 'table'`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/82889/298479)
- MS SQL: [`SELECT Distinct TABLE_NAME FROM information_schema.TABLES`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6598435/298479)
- Oracle: [`SELECT table_name FROM all_tables`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/205746/298479)
- SAP HANA: [`SELECT table_name FROM tables`](http://help.sap.de/hana/SAP_HANA_SQL_and_System_Views_Reference_en.pdf)

Comment: Now that's what I call an answer

Comment: @user1458476: We have SO as a knowledgebase, what do you expect? :-P